# Why does a 30-day cookie expire when the browser is closed?

Tags: php, cookies

I have written a PHP script to create a cookie that has a 30-day lifetime.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  $cookie_name = 'user';
  $cookie_value = 'John Doe';

  setcookie($cookie_name, 
            $cookie_value, 
            time() + (86400 * 30),      # 86400 = 24h x 60m x 60s
            '/');
```

Since this cookie has a life of 30-days, even if I close the browser, it should remain.

However, I find that when I close the browser and then restart the browser, the cookie can't be retrieved.

I'd like to ask:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Using PHP, how can I ensure a cookie remains?

Comment: Make sure your browser is not set to delete cookies on close, or that you're using the browser in incognito/private mode

Comment: In regards to "*Using PHP, how can I ensure a cookie remains?*", you will not be able to override user's choice in handling cookies (browser settings, incognito, extensions which clean cookies etc).

Comment: @aynber, the option "Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed" is disabled in my Firefox browser. I am using a normal (public) session.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I am the developer and (in this case) the user too. I was referring to my own usage session in this case.

Comment: @SSteven Ah. In that event, its still driven by the user's end and you won't be able to ensure cookies exist from PHP's end. There is something setup that is causing your cookie to get wiped. As the `setcookie()` usage you show, should be setting a non-session-only cookie. Have you tried switching to using the options signature instead with 'secure' and 'httponly' flags on (php7+)?

Comment: PS: I have just found out this happening only in Firefox. On Chrome, the cookie is preserved after the browser is closed. This appears to be a Firefox issue, though in my case, the "Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed" option is disabled.

Comment: This may be helpful with firefox's cookie settings: https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1253515